# Follow and display currently focused element on a webpage

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to debug the tab index flow through a deployed webpage. The current css has outline:none on many of the input elements.

What is the best way, in chrome, to do a global css override, so that I can clearly see the selected/focused element while tabbing through the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the element on the page (right-click it and select "inspect"), right-click it in the elements tab, select ":focus" from the list, look in the styles tab (should already be open) for the style rule setting the `outline:none` rule, uncheck the checkbox next to all `outline:none` styles (you may need to scroll or uncheck them from multiple rules).  This will allow you to see the default outline style in your browser without changing code on production.  You will have to repeat these steps every time you open the page to test it.

Edit: Those steps should cover most cases that you need to do that.  If you truly need a global rule, you can add that too by clicking the "+" icon in the styles tab and adding a rule similar to `*:focus{outline:initial !important}` or similar.

Comment: that is what I am not looking to do. but thanks! I do not want to have to manually change every one. maybe something like :focus {outline: red solid 2px; !important} globally

Comment: See my edit.  `*:focus { outline: red solid 2px !important; }` would do it using the "+" icon in the styles tab.

Comment: doing so adds the rule, however it is grayed out. changing element or tabbing removes the rule.

Comment: It's only greyed out because it doesn't apply to the currently selected element in the elements tab.  Just click back on the page and hit tab a couple times, you'll see it take effect.

Comment: clicking out of the element then tabbing applied the css. thanks!